# MvvmCross ViewModel lifecycle during rotation

Tags: mvvmcross

I have been using Mvvmcross to develop Android application. I am dealing with the issue of ViewModel lifecycle during a rotation. It seems that generally ViewModel is preserved during a rotation. However this is not the case when I present ViewModels in MvxTabActivity. When the rotation happens it always calls a ViewModel constructor.

I have used similar code structure as in N+1 tutorial https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/tree/master/N-25-Tabbed.

Is there a way to modify this tutorial to keep ViewModels in memory during rotation when using MvxTabActivity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default ViewModel caching which attempts to workaround the Android rotation behaviour is based around `IMvxSingleViewModelCache` - so it's not too surprising it can't cope with multiple Activities and multiple ViewModels.

For where this interface is declared and used, see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/search?q=IMvxSingleViewModelCache&ref=cmdform

If this behaviour is troubling you, then you should be able to work around it by one of :

#### 1. Use fragment based tabs rather than Activity based ones

Android handles Fragment lifecycle differently to Activity ones.

#### 2. Or continue using activity based tabs, but implement your own `IMvxSingleViewModelCache`

It should be simple, for example, to identify your child view models with by their 'Child' naming convention.

With this done you can then implement something like:

```
public class MyCustomViewModelCache
    : IMvxSingleViewModelCache
{
    private const string BundleCacheKey = "__mvxVMCacheKey";

    private int _counter;

    private IMvxViewModel _currentViewModel;

    public void Cache(IMvxViewModel toCache, Bundle bundle)
    {
        if (toCache != null
            && toCache.GetType().Name.StartsWith("Child"))
        {
            // don't worry about caching child view models
            return;
        }

        _currentViewModel = toCache;
        _counter++;

        if (_currentViewModel == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        bundle.PutInt(BundleCacheKey, _counter);
    }

    public IMvxViewModel GetAndClear(Bundle bundle)
    {
        var storedViewModel = _currentViewModel;
        _currentViewModel = null;

        if (bundle == null)
            return null;

        var key = bundle.GetInt(BundleCacheKey);
        var toReturn = (key == _counter) ? storedViewModel : null;
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

This class based on [MvxSingleViewModelCache.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxSingleViewModelCache.cs) with just one small addition.

You can register an instance of this class as the `IMvxSingleViewModelCache` singleton during the `InitializeLastChance` of your Setup.

```
  Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxSingleViewModelCache>(new MyCustomViewModelCache());
```

With this done, the home/tab activity should (I think) continue to work - and it'll pass the viewmodels down to the tab children after rotation.

(Other possibilities for `IMvxSingleViewModelCache` are possible - e.g. it could cache multiple view models - but please don't let it cache too many view models for too long or you may run into 'out of memory' conditions)

#### 3. Or switch the Android rotation handling off

If you add the `android:configChanges="orientation"` flag (or it's monodroid equivalent Attribute) then you can just handle the rotation yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. I have used fragment based tabs and it works exactly the way I need.