# What kind of magic does MvvmCross do to handle activity rotation/recreation?

Tags: android, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

Given that activities normally get recreated when the device is rotated,

what kind of magic does MvvmCross do to allow for these 2 things?
1) "long-living" (longer than activities) view models
2) "automatic" update of the views even if an activity was recreated midway-through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, MvvmCross doesn't really work with any view model that lives longer than it's view - the default viewmodel locator provides a new viewmodel for every view.

There is a small exception for Android specifically to handle this rotation - on Android, there is a single viewmodel cache which will cache the last seen viewmodel for one appearance only - see the code in [MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs#L46](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxActivityViewExtensions.cs#L46) and [MvxSingleViewModelCache.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid/Views/MvxSingleViewModelCache.cs)

There is a known issue that the cache will not work for Tabbed Activities which contain other Activities - see [MvvmCross ViewModel lifecycle during rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503815/mvvmcross-viewmodel-lifecycle-during-rotation/17504284#17504284)

"automatic" update of the views is handled by Mvvm data-binding - the UI Views bind to the current state in the ViewModels whatever that state is.